# Como pegar vários grupos numa Regex?

Tags: c#, string, regex

```
    public string site = "http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&world=Aurera";
    private Regex nomedochar = new Regex("subtopic=characters&name=(?<player>.*?)\" >");
    public string nomedochar2 = "";
    public Thread t;
    public List<string> player = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.nomedochar2 = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(site).GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();        
        Match math = this.nomedochar.Match(this.nomedochar2);

        this.player.Add(math.Groups["player"].Value);
        this.t = new Thread(Novathread);
        this.t.Start();
    }
    public void Novathread()
    {    
       for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++);
    }
```

Eu queria que ele pegasse todos os "player" que achasse e botasse em uma list box, mas eu não consigo, estou aprendendo a programar agora.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em alternativa à solução do Filipe aqui fica algo mais para aprenderes.

A tua implementação bloqueia a UI quando está a obter o conteúdo da página, o que não é uma boa experiência para o utilizador. Com a `.NET Framework 4.5` e o `C# 5.0` tornou-se muito mais fácil a programação assíncrona, pelo que podes tirar partido disso.

Quanto à expressão regular, ao invés de capturar um padrão, neste caso, pode-se capturar o que está rodeado por padrões. Para testares e desenvolveres as tuas expressões regulares, recomendo o [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var players = await GetPlayersAsync("http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&world=Aurera");

    this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(players);
}

private async Task<string[]> GetPlayersAsync(string url)
{
    var text = await (new HttpClient()).GetStringAsync(url);

    var regex = new Regex("(?<=\\?subtopic\\=characters&name\\=)[^\"]*(?=\")");

    var matches = regex.Matches(text);

    return (from match in matches.Cast<Match>()
            select match.Value.Replace('+', ' ')).ToArray().Dump();;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
this.nomedochar2 = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(site).GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();        
MatchCollection matches = nomedochar.Matches(nomedochar2);

this.player = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Groups["player"].Value.Replace("+", " ")).ToList();
foreach (var item in player)
{
    listBox1.Add(item);
}
```